# Can we switch between Forms Authentication and Azure AD authentication dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, openid-connect, forms-authentication, multi-tenant

I have a Asp.Net web form application which uses form authentication. However, I need to migrate to Azure AD authentication for some users. I want to decide the authentication type dynamically, based on the tenant id in current request context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.